# Angular doesn't update view on blurred browser tab

Tags: javascript, angular

I reproduced this behaviour on Chrome and Firefox.

If Angular Application is opened in not active tab in browser
and when I use router.navigate

for example

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate([
        '/detail', '5243524'
    ]);
}, 10000);
```

all requests and logic on that page are performed, title in tab is changed, but data on page is still old.
Data is updated only when I click on blurred browser tab with application, and make it active. Data updating takes less than a second, but in my case it is critical.

Do someone have any ideas why I have this issue?
Is it expected behaviour for Angular 2 apps?
Is there any method to force page updating in blurred browser tab?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Blurred browser tabs are throttled in both Chrome and Firefox, which limits them by number of instructions. This is intentional, and not Angular specific. See [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs) for more info on Chrome.

Comment: Benedict Lewis, Thank you very much!